# Using multiple Conditions in Intellij Debugger Breakpoint

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, conditional-breakpoint

I want to add multiple conditions to a breakpoint in IntelliJ. 
Something like:

```
stringA.equals("test") && objectA.equals(objectB);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So adding a return statment in front of the statment solved the problem.

[image: without return]

[image: with return]

Comment: Your original question didn't mention that you've added the semicolon. Please see the note in my answer about it.

Answer (score 6):

IntelliJ IDEA breakpoint condition can be [any boolean expression](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html):

> Select to specify a condition for hitting a breakpoint.   A condition is
>   a Java Boolean expression including a method returning    true or false,
>   for example, str1.equals(str2).
>
> This expression must be valid at the line where the breakpoint is set,
>   and it is evaluated each time the breakpoint is hit.  If the evaluation
>   result is true, the selected actions are performed.
>
> You can enter multi-line expressions, for example:
>
> ```
> if (myvar == expectedVariable) {
>   System.out.println(myvar);
>   anotherVariable = true;
> }
> return true;
> ```

`stringA.equals("test") && objectA.equals(objectB)` appears to be a valid expression returning `true` or `false`, so it should work right out of the box.

Proof of work:

[image: condition]

[image: breakpoint hit]

The following condition statement will also work:

```
return stringA.equals("test") && objectA.equals(objectB);
```

Please note that there is a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162408) which will show a red underline after the condition indicating that semicolon is expected. If you add the semicolon, the condition will become invalid and you will have to also add a `return` statement to make it valid again. It's a cosmetic issue and you can either use the condition without semicolon and ignore the error or you can add the semicolon and `return` to make it a valid statement:

[image: statement]

Comment: No, Intellij shows an error with the message not a statment.

Comment: @ChristianSchulze please see the updated answer showing that it works as described in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.2.

Comment: Ok the first one didn't work but the second one with adding a return works. Maybe because I use the Intellij CE and not the Ultimate Editon.

Comment: @ChristianSchulze No, it's because of the added semicolon, please see the note in my answer about the known issue related to it. You either add a semicolon and return or you don't add the semicolon.